# Kafka Aiven GCS Sink Connector - Files got overwritten every minute

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, aiven

aiven version: `0.13.0`
kafka version: `3.5.1`

this is my connector configuration:

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.aiven.kafka.connect.gcs.GcsSinkConnector",
  "tasks.max": "4",
  "topics": "loan_logs",
  "gcs.credentials.path": "<credspath>",
  "gcs.bucket.name": "datalake-raw",
  "file.name.prefix": "lsm/",
  "file.name.timestamp.timezone": "Asia/Jakarta",
  "file.name.template": "{{topic}}/sink_date={{timestamp:unit=yyyy}}{{timestamp:unit=MM}}{{timestamp:unit=dd}}/sink_hour={{timestamp:unit=HH}}/p{{partition:padding=false}}-{{start_offset:padding=true}}.snappy.parquet",
  "file.compression.type": "snappy",
  "format.output.fields": "key,value,offset,timestamp,headers",
  "format.output.type": "parquet",
  "format.output.envelope": "true",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "behavior.on.null.values": "ignore"
}
```

Some of files written by connector in the designated bucket has 0 bytes, I wonder if this is normal behavior. Then at some point the files will get overwritten every minute by the connector until next hour (the files are divided by sink hour directory) and it keeps happening again. I found out that overwriting can be happened should kafka reprocess the messages, but why kafka need to reprocess them?

I also found this error in connector logs, not sure if they are related with the issue:

```
2024-02-09 04:06:01,665 ERROR [de-lsm-gcs-connector|task-1] WorkerSinkTask{id=de-lsm-gcs-connector-1} Offset commit failed, rewinding to last committed offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask) [task-thread-de-lsm-gcs-connector-1]
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.aiven.kafka.connect.gcs.GcsSinkTask.flushFile(GcsSinkTask.java:131)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.forEach(Collections.java:1553)
    at io.aiven.kafka.connect.gcs.GcsSinkTask.flush(GcsSinkTask.java:114)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkTask.preCommit(SinkTask.java:125)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.commitOffsets(WorkerSinkTask.java:407)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.commitOffsets(WorkerSinkTask.java:377)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:221)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:206)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:202)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:257)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
...
2024-02-09 04:06:01,665 ERROR [de-lsm-gcs-connector|task-1] WorkerSinkTask{id=de-lsm-gcs-connector-1} Commit of offsets threw an unexpected exception for sequence number 124: null (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask) [task-thread-de-lsm-gcs-connector-1]
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.aiven.kafka.connect.gcs.GcsSinkTask.flushFile(GcsSinkTask.java:131)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.forEach(Collections.java:1553)
    at io.aiven.kafka.connect.gcs.GcsSinkTask.flush(GcsSinkTask.java:114)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkTask.preCommit(SinkTask.java:125)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.commitOffsets(WorkerSinkTask.java:407)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.commitOffsets(WorkerSinkTask.java:377)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:221)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:206)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:202)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:257)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
...
```

I am using the same configuration in different kafka with version `3.3` and aiven `0.9.0` and there has not been any issue similar to this. Is there any new configuration I am missing?

some of the messages has NULL key, is this somehow related?

Comment: thanks for reporting this issue. I'd need more info on how to reproduce it to be able to help: 
- could you provide enough topic config, sample messages and timing information on how to reproduce this issue?
- could you provide examples on how the output structure looks like in GCS when running v0.13 vs v0.9?
Ideally, if you could prepare an integration test (like https://github.com/Aiven-Open/gcs-connector-for-apache-kafka/blob/main/src/integration-test/java/io/aiven/kafka/connect/gcs/ParquetIntegrationTest.java) that reproduces this issue would help to investigate further.

Comment: Also, if you prefer, let's create an issue here https://github.com/Aiven-Open/gcs-connector-for-apache-kafka/issues and follow up the discussion there. If we come up with a solution, let's bring back to SO

Comment: thanks for your response @jeqo, actually I've created a github issue [here](https://github.com/Aiven-Open/gcs-connector-for-apache-kafka/issues/347)

Comment: would you prefer me providing topic config and so on in the github issue as well? I need to ask our devops team for the configs though, I'll soon get back to you once I gather everything. Unfortunately I am not familiar with this integration test in java, is there step by step available somewhere I can follow to get this running?

Comment: Thanks! sorry I miss the issue was already there. If not familiar with running the integration test, I will try to reproduce it with the info provided then. Let's follow up on the github issue then